Am I required to go into an employer to manage banking for pay they owe me after I no longer work for them?
I have been doing the run/call around all week to chase down my paycheck that my previous employer owes me...Checked everything on my end, called the bank to see if it maybe bounced (it didn't)...
Finally got consistent communication from said employer after I told them I'd make a file to Department of Labor... Again, they kept directing me to other people and told me to contact the bank, which I again did...Now they want me to go into the head office (over an hour away for me, on toll roads too) to resupply/check my banking info.
To be honest, with the way I was treated this last week-I don't feel comfortable. I've had similar instances when I started working as a young teen, but was able to resolve it over the phone/online. I get identity theft but something feels off to me...
Bottom line: Do I suck it up, go in? Or just make the file? I've tried being nice, and patient but it's enough-it's been 2 weeks since I was supposed to be paid.

How did this company pay you before you stopped working for them ? Can they continue to use this same method to pay you ?

Just go ahead and call your Department of Labor.  I'm not sure of your location, but in the US, they are required to give you your final pay within a certain time frame (it varies by state), and it's not up to you to make that happen.

Since they are large enough to have at least 2 offices, call the Home Office's HR and politely speak to them. Follow up with an email.
They have all your info on file. Unless something has changed, politely remind anyone that is jerking you around of that.
Document each interation - JUST IN CASE you have to file with the department of labor.
Email the company's President or Chief Legal Officer (if they have one).
Legally, there is nothing worse than messing with someone's payroll. A responsible business just doesn't do it.
Bottom line, be polite, don't take no or being pushed off for an answer. Only accept the specific date you will receive your money. Email them back your understanding of the conversation.
RANT: As a business owner, businesses mistreating people irks me to no end.
Good Luck.

Whoever's passing the buck around has NO idea what kind of trouble they're inviting, and there's no way higher ups would let them do this. This is definitely something that upper management will address directly and swiftly, because it is pretty easy to prove that you weren't paid.

Amen to that. As a business in the US, you just don't mess with people's pay. The repercussions are very serious. When I hear story like this, it usually a single person acting out and not the company.

If you have someone higher in the hierarchy you were on good terms with, ask for their help. Be polite, be understanding, and just ask for help.
You previous boss would be an obvious pick; you should still be able to reach him via e-mail. Ask for his/her help, he/she will likely be able and willing to help. If you know someone higher up, that is even better.
Management understands how unacceptable it is to mess with employees' salaries - even if they have already left. It is a huge risk they will not want to take. And they have access to all internal communication channels, ticketing systems, org charts that you probably don't have access to anymore.
I had a similar issue, it was not paycheck but an important document that the company didn't provide me when I left. After running around in circles for weeks, I send a mail to the country manager whom I had coffee with not more than 2-3 times in 2 years. He replied with an apology on behalf of the company and promised to look into it. HR called me within 24 hours to tell me they found my document.
So I'd say before you drive there, try contacting someone that might remember and help you.

In my state of California, we have:
Labor code 201 says employees who quit must receive their final paycheck within 72 hrs.  Employees who are terminated must be paid on the same day.
Labor code 210 makes penalties for employers who pay late.
All the states will have laws to protect people from employers who want to get over on them, as in your case.  Low-wage people are victimized in these situations because the employers know the people often don't have the means or time to get the law involved, and count on this to get away with the stuff they do.
If you're being blown off over a so-called direct deposit issue, there is nothing stopping them from writing you a paper check.  If I were you, I'd demand a check.  Make a phone call, but also send your demand in writing (email is fine) and keep a copy to start a paper trail.  If they've already been dragging their heels, specify that you need a check by express mail (UPS/Fedex) within 24 hours.  Get a tracking number.  Don't burn fuel to show up at their offices and have them jerk you around.  If you still get push back, get the state involved.
Sorry about these people playing with your money.  That sucks!
I am not an attorney, and this does not constitute legal advice.
